# xcode 4.5.2 upgrade issue

Tags: xcode, upgrade

With previous version of xcode works perfectly for my cocos2d and box2d project

but today i upgrad it(to xcode 4.5.2) because my iphone device was having os version issue.

and then all of my upgrade progress finished

i have some trouble with in it

when i run the project in new xcode, it started complain me that i have no Default.png

but i'am already have defalult.png in my project

so why this happening ? and how can i figure it out...

i've already clean and rebuild 
and also delete default.png and recopy from original arsenal
but same problem occurred

(as you guess .. i'm not good at explain my opinion in english..  sorry for that.. )

Answer (score 0):

I expect you mean this:

Missing - "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image"

That is the startup image for the iPhone 5 screen. If you click on the warning it will create one for you.

Comment: @2x and 568h@2x but result is same

Comment: Check that they are all included in "Copy Bundle Resources" in your project target Build Phases

Comment: now i am delete all of default*.png and copy of box2d template's default.png file and then that crash cleared and loading layer works ok with it's image but main screen have same problem OMG T_T

Comment: Thank's for all but i'an still in it. i can't find it's crash rule

Comment: now i am trying to delete all of resources from my project and will process [He Was]'s rule..

Comment: Sorry ^^ as developer we use immense resources for reaching certain goals.. In my case use lower case filename instead of "Default.png" but previous version of xcode correct work for me.. if you have same problem first look over your resources filename is correct and exactly same in source code .. some version of xcode doesn't matter but new version of xcode crash your app .. Give special thank's to [He Was] for your kindness